# How to execute javascript codes with Nodejs child_process and Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, child-process

I am aware that child_process can be used in executing linux command. Can I used it in executing Meteor server-side codes?

I would like to use spawn in creating a process that will execute my loop.
My loop does console log in every minute.

```
myLoop(){
    setInterval(function(){ console.log("test"); }, 60000);
}
```

I would like this to execute in a different process. So it will optimize my server resources.

Can I used this code?

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const loop= spawn(myLoop);

loop.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
});

loop.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
});
```

This is not working in my Meteor App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `child_process.fork()` method, it's like `spawn` but create a node.js process with the asked module: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

Comment: can you give me some example how to use fork with a method that will call console.log?